# Can I put the quarto files of the posts of my blog directly in the posts directory instead of in separate directories?

Tags: blogs, directory-structure, quarto

I have a small private blog based on [quarto](https://quarto.org/).

I am wondering if there are any drawbacks in putting the posts in the manner "posts/2023-07-03-my-post-title.qmd" instead of in "posts/2023-07-03-my-post-title/index.qmd".

If tried and it seems to work fine and I like it a lot better, but before changing my entire blog I wanted to check if there are any relevant drawbacks that I currently don't see.

Many thanks in advance and best greetings,
Sebastian

Comment: What I did and what works without any drawbacks noticed so far:

I put my posts in "posts/2023-07-12-my-post-title/2023-07-12-my-post-title.qmd". This way, I can easily search for a file to open in my editor and don't get confused with plenty tabs in my editor with "index.qmd"-files.